# RainLoop - Pass values in a URL link and automatically Sign In

Tags: html, url, webmail

I am trying to pass a value using a link.
For example, if I want to add an email and password for a user to Sign In straight away in the [RainLoop](http://demo.rainloop.net/) webmail.

I am trying using

```
http://demo.rainloop.net/?RainLoopEmail="new@email.com"&RainLoopPassword="12345"
```

or

```
http://demo.rainloop.net/?RainLoopEmail="new@email.com"&RainLoopPassword="12345"#ID
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but you will have to rewrite the rainloop PHP files by yourself. Also parsing passwords via the GET method is a very bad idea. Get commands will stay in your history so everyone who types in 
    `demo.rainloop.net` will see the `?RainLoopPassword="12345"` also. It's not recommended, but possible. Another safer solution will be using the POST method. I suspect you will use this for you bookmarks or something? You can make an AJAX page which sends a POST request with the username and password to `demo.rainloop.net`. This way nobody will see your passwords and the effect is the same.

EDIT: For using an AJAX page you have to own a webserver, or register on a free hosting like `http://freehostingnoads.net`